# Keycloak integration with browser authentication flow

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am currently integrating Keycloak into a rather complicated spring boot application environment with custom AuthenticationProvider implementation (so I am not using the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider). In my case I aim to use OIDC authentication protocol with `Browser` flow.

So, when a client navigates to the login page of my spring application, he is redirected to the keycloak login page. This is already working.

There, once he authenticates, he gets redirected back to the initial application page. And this is where I am struggling about how to proceed.

Once the keycloak redirects me back to my application, by making a GET request to my application and specifies the `session_state` and `code` parameters. I assume that these probably can be used to authenticate the client in further communication but I am not sure whether my assumption is correct and, if yes, how would I use these values. Sadly I wasn't able to find this information in the documentation...

So my questions are:

1. For a browser based OIDC authentication, is my approach correct?
2. Am I correct at assuming that the `session_state` and `code` variables can help me to authenticate the client in my web application?
3. How do I use these values for authentication?

I hope I could deliver my struggle and thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

After Keycloak redirects a user to your application you exchange the received code for access and id tokens. Access token is used in requests to resource servers.

To exchange authorization code use this request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://KEYCLOAK/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=authorization_code \
  --data 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
  --data client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET \
  --data code=CODE \
  --data 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI'
```

Omit `client_secret` in case of public client.

Here you can read more about `Authorization Code` (browser) flow:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#authorization-code-flow